# How to user a custom jsonp callback in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I am trying to configure Jsonp.get to use a custom **JSONP_CALLBACK** method in Angular 2. 
when i do something like this:

```
this.jsonp.get(`${url}?callback=content`)
  .map(this.checkForError)
  .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
  .map(this.getJson);
```

i get the error:

```
file.json?callback=content:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation, but there is already a pull request pending

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13175

Comment: Thanks for your reply Günter, do you have any temporal solution for this issue other than using 3rd party lib like fetch-jsonp?

Comment: No, no other solution.